What rigify bones should I map a mocap .bvh armature onto for retargeting?
I am trying to write a script that retargets a mocap .bvh file onto my rigify armature. Ideally I would just rename the bones in the .bvh armature to match my rig and change the action in the action editor. I'm not sure which bone names to use though. It doesn't seem to work if I just map every bone onto its ORG- counterpart bone.
If I apply constraints to the joints and bake the animation, it only works if I clear the rigify constraints first. I'd like to keep those in tact for animating later scenes. Here's a portion of my code:
    bone_mapping = create_bone_mapping() # This is a dict of the .bvh bone names and their corresponding rigify ORG- bone names. e.g. "Spine": "ORG-spine.001"
    original_constraints = store_constraints(rigify_armature) # Goes through each bone in the armature and stores the constraint in an object that is returned
    set_constraints(bvh_armature, rigify_armature, bone_mapping) # Set rotation constraints to my rigify rig to follow the bvh rig
    bpy.ops.nla.bake(
        frame_start=bpy.context.scene.frame_start,
        frame_end=bpy.context.scene.frame_end,
        only_selected=False,
        visual_keying=True,
        clear_constraints=True,
        use_current_action=True,
        clean_curves=True,
        bake_types={'POSE'}
    )
    remove_constraints(rigify_armature, bone_mapping) # Deletes the bvh constraint I added above
    re_add_original_constraints(rigify_armature, original_constraints) # Re-attaches the original rigify constraints. Everything works fine if I comment this line out

I either need to know how to rename the .bvh bone names better so I can just change the action, or know how to update the script to bake the animation and keep the constraints.

I think I found a solution. The mapping is a bit messy. Mostly mapping to the fk bones and a few original bones. https://bitbucket.org/Diffeomorphic/retarget_bvh/src/407a1ab5758dd9a05de3badc250781a65141ac77/known_rigs/rigify4.json#lines-6
